# Como cambiar la URL sin hacer redirect una vez abierto un archivo

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

tengo una consulta:
Tengo un Hyperlink, que durante el DataBound le seteo el NavigateURL para que abra un archivo usando un path, este es mi código:

```
public void SetearNavURL(ref hyperlink btn){
  btn.navigateurl = path;
}
```

El tema, es que que queda expuesta en la URL la direccion física del archivo en cuestion.
Hay alguna forma de borrar la url y renombrarla una vez abierto el adjunto ?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Yo ayer me enfrenté a un problema parecido, pero en next.js, fijate si te sirve ``window.history.pushState(null, "", "/urlRenombrada");``, yo ejecutaba eso una vez abierta la pagina en la que queria "esconder" la url

Comment: Con JavaScript puedes crear el elemento hyperlink, agregarle la URL, disparar el evento click, y luego borrarlo, en el mismo script